# Add multiple buttons over Card in Dialog flow webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have to add multiple buttons on Card or Basic card. Is it possible ?
In dialog flow documentation, its mentioned there is one element buttons which takes array of element. Based on this I have added buttons like:

```
agent.add(new BasicCard({
          title: body.hits.hits[i]._source.name,
          formattedText: '',
          image: {
               url: body.hits.hits[i]._source.images ? body.hits.hits[i]._source.images[0].src : '',
                                  accessibilityText: 'Logo',
            },
          buttons: [{
                    title: "Buy",
                    openUrlAction: {
                       url: body.hits.hits[i]._source.buy,
                      }
                  },{
                   title: "Add to Cart",
                   openUrlAction: {
                          url: body.hits.hits[i]._source.aad_to_card,
                       }
                  }

          ],

        }));
```

But its throws error as below:

```
throw new Error(`Unknown response type: "${JSON.stringify(response)}"`);
```

Some places its mentioned buttons takes only one element. So what's the point of making it array ?

Answer (score 0):

A [BasicCard](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) can only have one button. That is the current rule. I can't give a good reason on why it is in an array even if it only accepts one element.